# Facebook Login produces a blank pop-up window after login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

We are currently having a very weird problem when developing a page which utilises the "Login with Facebook" functionality.

We followed everything here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

and when FB.login() is called, we get a pop-up window asking us to login as expected. Logging in works on Chrome and Firefox, but on some user's IE (7-9), they get a blank page after login.

We tried to do a view-source on that supposed blank page and this is the contents:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var message = "cb=f14c5171603fa58&origin=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fmy.domain.com\u00252Ff3105069ef9fcf8&domain=my.domain.com&relation=opener&frame=f3050298de22b24&access_token=AAAGu5Dg83xMBAKsmr68aqYXSzWeDapHlGgkZAnA5NllE5QauaBTd2ZA8R6vQZAf7voi9g6u1ZCFOVttXZAZAmVl8dJZAedDrQMZAKrUTpGbIliyzLIOHPZB7m&expires_in=4641&signed_request=CXSX5CFXnYSV_-8S1iUFl1dFifl8B5D33vxBgaxdE3w.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiJBUUFsekxJaVh3TExQT1labUpWcG40cWlEMXVVN2hmMzVqdUJBbzJuSXpQMGdqVG1wMzc3NnFPZ2lIX3N6dVVzLUhVbVQ3enFHZGQzZ05LNTFyVEpDaXRlSG1Sc0V4Y2V2aTVqa04xVk1zQk1Za0ZYWHAwRHZjTjBUUHFlSUN1NWV5c0llWU01cGY1SGxLYk9VTWd6NXpuNzVRa3VwZFQtZGxpZlI0eGRLVEtUSUMyelJtc2N5bHRtSWZpOWJOQTBCVk1aVno3Y2tkcW43T0I1d0N6N2NzVDciLCJpc3N1ZWRfYXQiOjEzNTM0MDQ1NTksInVzZXJfaWQiOiIxMDAwMDQ2MTY1MDQwOTEifQ&base_domain=my.domain.com", origin = "http:\/\/my.domain.com\/f3105069ef9fcf8", domain = "my.domain.com";document.domain='facebook.com';(function(){var a=window.opener||window.parent,b='fb_xdm_frame_'+location.protocol.replace(':','');function c(){try{a.frames[b].proxyMessage(message,[domain]);}catch(e){setTimeout(c,100);}}function d(){__fbNative.postMessage(message,origin);}if(window===top&&/FBAN\/\w+;/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){if(window.__fbNative&&__fbNative.postMessage){d();}else window.addEventListener('fbNativeReady',d);}else c();})();

</script>
```

In order to isolate the problem, we also tried using the Facebook Login Button widget here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

but the results are the same. On those people's IE, the pop-up window becomes a blank page after they login and the window remains open.

We have tried to search all over the web and in StackOverflow for solutions but none worked.

Can any of the experts here help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're having exactly the same problem, but with Firefox (rather new versions) on PC and MAC... IE and Chrome works fine.

Comment: Same here. Only on microsoft edge. I used the debugger and found out that it's failing at sending proxyMessage back to the origin window. But somehow in the facebook example page it works. Maybe it's Edge's problem related to allowing popup. It seems that quite a lot of people are experiencing same issue. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/582468375439249/